# Animation problem when using thread

Tags: android, android-widget

so i'm having a imageview and i have applied translate animation to it whose positions are the points where user touches...its working fine...bt when i added a time updater to the activity which is obviously running on a thread...the translate animation starts behaving abnormally, i.e. it just go out of bounds....i tried different methods..nothing worked..i eliminated the time udater and used dgital clock widget..but again it doesn't work as digital clock alse uses threads to update time...

take a look at the translate animation code

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        float f1 = event.getX();
        swidth=image.getWidth();
        ((MaskedTextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)image.getLayoutParams();
        barwidth=bar.getWidth();
        bwidth=barwidth-swidth;
        android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams localLayoutParams2 = localLayoutParams;
        localLayoutParams2.leftMargin=(int) event.getX();
        if (localLayoutParams.leftMargin<bwidth && f1<bwidth)
        {
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(localLayoutParams.leftMargin,f1, 0, 0);
         anim.setStartOffset(0L);
            anim.setDuration(500L);         
            anim.setFillBefore(true);
            image.startAnimation(anim);
            image.invalidate();
        }
    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        float f1=event.getX();
        android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)image.getLayoutParams();


        if(f1<bwidth)
        {   
        TranslateAnimation anim=new TranslateAnimation(f1,0,0,0);   
        anim.setStartOffset(0L);
        anim.setDuration(500L);
        anim.setFillBefore(true);
        image.startAnimation(anim);
        image.invalidate();
        }
        else
        {
            if(soundsEnabled && !silent)
            mpDot.start();
            SwipeImage.this.finish();
        }


    }
    return true;
}
```

and this is the simple code of updating time every 60 seconds..

```
 new Timer().schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 0, 60000);

 public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hr;

            if(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getApplicationContext()))
                 hr=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            else
                 hr=c.get(Calendar.HOUR);

            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            if(minute<10)
                timeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(hr)+":0"+String.valueOf(minute));
            else
            timeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(hr)+":"+String.valueOf(minute));


        }
    };

    public void run() {

        handler.post(runnable);
        //invalidate();
    }
}*/
```

plz help me out guys...i just dont understand why its happening....thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a very costly operation in `onTouch`. Animation is not required to move a view along with the users finger. What you need to do is in `onTouch` just update the view position(set new `LayoutParams`) and invalidate.

Comment: got your point but i have to show smooth movement..dats why m using animation...okay if i xclude it...den thread problem will be resolved??

Comment: No idea about that. I think animation doesnt help in smoothing movement in such case. Removing the animation should improve the overall performance while dragging a view.

Comment: no use...its not the answer to my problem...also without animation the effect is not smooth..it doesnt moves with the finger..instead it just shows up when finger is moved..thx 4 da effort by the way

Comment: u need to do that stuff in ACTION_DOWN also.